# Gyro Calibration in 4.3 (mentioned solutions not working)

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, calibration, gyroscope

i have a Sony Xperia SP running Android 4.3 and have a problem with my Gyro not being calibrated. 
I don't have the Gyroscope calibration option any more - seems having been removed in 4.3.
The other Tools mentioned do calibrate G-Sensors, but not the Gyro.
The Sensor Kinetics app definitely shows that the gyro is not calibrated (turning cube on the gyro demo).
Problem is that no Google Cardboard app is working, all apps are tilting to lower right with a speed of 360degrees in ~ 70 seconds.

So, how can i calibrate my Gyro?
Why is the feature being removed in 4.3 compared to 4.2?
many thanks
Kay